# How to install PMD plugin in MyEclipse without using software update?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, pmd, myeclipse

I think due to network restictions in my company I am not able to install PMD using

Sotware Update->Find and Install.

I tried these sites

http://pmd.sourceforge.net/eclipse

http://pmd.sf.net/eclipse

but network error occurs 'Unable to access '

Is there any place from where I can download the plugin as zip file and then put it into the plugins folder? Will that work?

I downloaded pmd-eclipse-1.8.0.zip from a site(which i dont remember now) and PMD option shows up on right clicking the project/files but options like 'Check code with PMD','Clear PMD violations' etc are not showing up on the context menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following (assuming you are allowed to connect eg. a pendrive at work). At home create a mirror of the update site with following command (use command line):

(more information: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Repository_Mirroring)

```
 ./eclipse -nosplash -verbose
  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication
  -source Insert Source URL (e.g. http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.4milestones/)
  -destination Insert Destination URL (e.g. file:/tmp/3.4milestonesMirror/)
```

This will create a local mirror. take that directory with its content to work, use a local update site pointing to the directory you copied over from your pendrive. If it has dependency that is not provided in PMD update site but somewhere else, I guess you will have to do the same with that dependency (create mirror...) and set up the update site location in your Eclipse properly (remove remote update sites...)

Answer (score 0):

You can [download the eclipse pmd files](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/) and follow the [official instructions](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/integrations.html#eclipse) using a local repository.  If your company blocks sourceforge, first you should complain - that is a developer site to browse docs and the like.  If you are allowed to e-mail the files or use a portable drive, you can transport them that way.

It seems much more likely that they block eclipse updates rather than sourceforge itself though.